# ydn-db async operation need to assign value to variable

Tags: ydn-db

I'm unable to assign variable from async operation  using callback .  `.done` didn't assign value to variable. Here my code :

```
var someGlobalVar = 0;
dbs.count('cfs_init').done(function(x) {

console.log('Total : ' + x); 
someGlobalVar = x;
}); 

console.log(someGlobalVar); // 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Your assignment works if you manually (or in setTimeout function) execute `console.log(someGlobalVar);`, *after* receiving done callback.

You are executing it before done callback and hence it is still `0`.